# What is this echo statement from Parse.com's API Docs supposed to do?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm working with Parse.com's PHP API. In [their documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide#files-retrieving-file-contents), it states:

> Retrieving File Contents
>
> How to best retrieve the file contents back depends on the context of your application. It's best if you can make the visitors browser do the work for you. Typically, that means rendering the file's URL into your output. Here we output an uploaded profile photo in an image tag:
>
> `$profilePhoto = $profile->get("photoFile");`
>
> `echo '![]()getURL() . '">';`    // <------what the heck is this?

**What exactly is `echo '![]()getURL() . '">';` supposed to do?**

Is this just a typo in the Documentation?

Surely they meant `echo '<img src="'.$profilePhoto->getURL() . '">';` ..right?

Or is this some weird shorthand I'm not aware of?

I'll report the typo to parse if someone can just confirm I'm not missing something.

Comment: The `"` after the second `'` causes a syntax error, this could hardly have been their intention. I'd contact them about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, this is an error. Since the docs are editable on Github; you can suggest a fix by [editing this file](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Docs/edit/master/en/php/files.mdown)